# Who owns the rights to plastic spoons now? (US D234017 S)

Tags: patentability, claims, ownership, search, usd234017

In reference to the patent: [USD234017](https://www.google.com/patents/USD234017)

Who owns the rights to plastic spoons now? Their patent was only to last 14 years

Answer (score 1):

'Ask Patents' user has already answered a similar question [Expiry date of patent no 6676109](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/5622/11895) but in your specific case you'll need to apply that answer as follows:

US MPEP 2701    Patent Term [R-11.2013] states that..

> Design patents have a term of fourteen years from the date of patent
>   grant, except for any design patent issued from applications filed on
>   or after the date of entry into force of the Hague Treaty as to the
>   United States, has a term of fifteen years from the date of patent
>   grant (see Pub. L. No. 112-211). See 35 U.S.C. 173 and MPEP § 1505.

above goes with duly payment of maintenance fee and subject to any invalidation or re-examination proceeding. if all above are full filled then a design patent to last 14 years after the expiry of said term patent will be in public domain.